# Cannot change cursor in a WinForms control at designt time

Tags: winforms, cursor, controls, windows-forms-designer, design-time

We have a WinForms control (inherits Systems.Windows.Forms.Control) with a custom designer attached to it (inherits ControlDesigner). We need to process some mouse events like clicks in a special area inside our control at design time. To indicate that mouse click is available in that area, we need to change the default 4-arrow cursor to something else - at least, to the standard arrow, but we could not find a way to do that.

We redefined the `ControlDesigner.GetHitTest` method to return true for that special click rectangle, but the cursor simply flashes when it is over the area. It is changed to the default arrow for some milliseconds, and then back to the 4-arrow cursor which implies the whole control can be selected and moved on the form. Overriding `ControlDesigner.OnSetCursor` does not have any effect as it seems this virtual method is called only when the cursor is changed to the default 4-arrow cursor. Games with `WndProc` (trying to intercept WM_MOUSE* events) did not get us any positive results too.

Even when we try to implement samples from related books (like the SimpleLineControl from Eric White's "GDI+ Programming-Creating Custom Controls Using C#"), we have the same behavior.

Our dev env is VS2010/.NET 4.0 which is the minimal requirement. How to make it work in this and later environments?

Comment: Use the MouseMove event.  Assign the Cursor property.

Comment: @HansPassant, If you mean the MouseMove event of the control itself, yes, we do that in it (we set Cursor.Current). In fact, we try to use the existing runtime functionality at design time. The problem is that the cursor is constantly changed back to the four headed arrow. Do you have a sample of how to do that? Maybe, I overlooked something in my dev...

Comment: I decompiled the ControlDesigner class to see where and when `ControlDesigner.OnSetCursor` is raised. It is done just once - in its `WndProc`. However, ControlDesigner's WndProc is enough complicated and it is hard to realize all cases when this call is done. Another thing I detected is that there is an equivalent `OnSetCursor` call if a so called `mouseHandler` of the `IMouseHandler` is defined. Maybe, we need to go this way? But I cannot find any good example of this technique, and if anybody can help me with that - it would be nice.